# How to automatically save files in a directory? multer nestjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, multer

How can `multer` on `nestjs` automatically save a file to a directory? I watched that if you register the `MulterModule` module and specify the path in it, all files will be saved to this path:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MulterModuleLib.register({
      dest: './uploads'
    })
  ]
})
export class MulterModule {
}
```

But it doesn't work, the `uploads` directory is not created and the files are not saved.

P.S `MulterModule` imported into `app.module`

I know that you can save everything manually, but I would like everything to work automatically.

Comment: Where are you checking for the `upload` directory? It should be under `<projectRoot>/dist` with that setup

Comment: @JayMcDoniel, I checked everywhere, including in the dist folder